# How to use $http and $location in directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am really new to Angular, and I have a stupid question regarding using $http and $location in directives. I am creating a todo list, and want to delete an entry when I click on a link.

Currently, I have set an attribute directive on the `<a>` and want it to make a delete call to my api when clicked (I was thinking if I were to do this in backbone, it would be akin to binding a click event, which triggers a call to remove the model from the collection, and I kinda structured my code accordingly?)

Directive

```
app.directive('delete', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          $http.delete('/api/posts/' + $routeParams.id).
            success(function(data) {
              $location.path('/app')  
            })
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Controller

```
app.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location'
function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $http.get('/api/posts').
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.posts = data.posts;
    })
}
]);
```

Markup

```
div(ng-controller='IndexCtrl')
  h1 Blog
  div 
    a.btn(href='/app/newpost') New Post
  ul
    li(ng-repeat='post in posts')
      a(href='/app/{{ post._id }}')
        h3 {{ post.title }}
        div {{ post.text }}
      a(href='/app/editpost/{{ post._id }}') Edit 
      a(href='#', delete id='{{post._id }}') Delete
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.directive('delete',['$http', '$location',function($http, $location) {
 //your code ..
}]);
```

the same way you do DI for controller